# Copying data to transient vertex buffer in bgfx causing SIGSEGV

Tags: rust, glfw, unsafe, bgfx

I'm trying to port an [bgfx](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx) application I wrote in C++ to Rust using [bgfx-rs](https://github.com/emoon/bgfx-rs). Everything works great, until I try to copy some vertex data from the application to an transient vertex buffer.

```rust
let vertices: [f32; 16] = [
    0.0f32,    0.0f32,    0.0f32,    0.0f32,
    1024.0f32, 0.0f32,    1024.0f32, 0.0f32,
    0.0f32,    1024.0f32, 0.0f32,    1024.0f32,
    1024.0f32, 1024.0f32, 1024.0f32, 1024.0f32,
];
let builder = bgfx::VertexLayoutBuilder::new();
builder.begin(RendererType::Noop);
builder.add(
    bgfx::Attrib::Position,
    2,
    bgfx::AttribType::Float,
    bgfx_rs::static_lib::AddArgs {
        normalized: false,
        as_int: false,
    },
);
builder.add(
    bgfx::Attrib::TexCoord0,
    2,
    bgfx::AttribType::Float,
    bgfx_rs::static_lib::AddArgs {
        normalized: false,
        as_int: false,
    },
);
builder.end();
let mut tvb = bgfx::TransientVertexBuffer::new();
if bgfx::get_avail_transient_vertex_buffer(4, &builder) == 4 {
    bgfx::alloc_transient_vertex_buffer(&mut tvb, 4, &builder);
    unsafe {
        let mut data = *tvb.data;
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
            vertices.as_ptr() as *const u8,
            &mut data,
            std::mem::size_of::<[f32; 16]>(),
        ); //this line causes SIGSEGV
    }
}
```

When I add this `std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping` operation the program is crashing due to SIGSEGV signal.

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

What is the best way to debug the cause of an SIGSEGV signal? I've tried running the code using GDB, but until the crash happens there is no indication of the reason visible at all (I can step through the signal handler but there is no additional information about the crash). If I copy less bytes (`std::mem::size_of::<[f32; 16]>()` resolves to 64 bytes; i.e. if I just copy 32 bytes instead) the application is not crashing (but obviously some of my vertex data is missing).

I'm using the unsafe block, because that is the only way I got my C++ code working fighting the borrow-checker. For reference my code in C++ (which works fine):

```cpp
const float vertices[16] = {
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  1024.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, 1024.0f, 0.0f, 1024.0f,
  1024.0f, 1024.0f, 1024.0f, 1024.0f
};
ms_decl // bgfx::VertexLayout
  .begin()
  .add(bgfx::Attrib::Position, 2, bgfx::AttribType::Float)
  .add(bgfx::Attrib::TexCoord0, 2, bgfx::AttribType::Float)
  .end();
bgfx::TransientVertexBuffer tvb;
if (bgfx::getAvailTransientVertexBuffer(4, ms_decl) == 4) {
  bgfx::allocTransientVertexBuffer(&tvb, 4,ms_decl);
  bx::memCopy(tvb.data, vertices, 16 * sizeof(float));
}
```

The reason I have to use `std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping` in the Rust version is that `tvb.data` is an `uint8_t*` in C++ ([reference](https://bkaradzic.github.io/bgfx/bgfx.html#_CPPv4N4bgfx21TransientVertexBufferE)), while it is `const u8*` in Rust ([reference](https://docs.rs/bgfx-rs/0.6.0/bgfx_rs/static_lib/struct.TransientVertexBuffer.html)).

Any help if there is something wrong in my unsafe block or how to get to the bottom of the SIGSEGV would be highly appreciated.

I have tried:

- using `std::ptr::copy` instead (I don't expect the source & destination memory to overlap), but still the same SIGSEGV occurred

Comment: *copy_nonoverlapping* — are your source and destination memory addresses non-overlapping? What if you use `copy` instead?

Comment: I tried using `std::ptr::copy` with the same result. Source & destination address should not overlap - I double-checked outputting the addresses using `println!("{:?}, {:?}", vertices.as_ptr() as *const u8, tvb.data as *mut u8);` and they are apart enough i.e.  `src: 0x7fff4de4a008, dst: 0x7f367efff040 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I am reading the correct [documentation](https://docs.rs/bgfx-rs/0.8.0/bgfx_rs/static_lib/struct.TransientVertexBuffer.html), the issue is you are copying to the stack instead of the data pointer. Since `tvb.data` is a `*mut u8`, the call `let mut data = *tvb.data;` dereferences the pointer and copies the value to the stack meaning the type of `data` is `u8`. Then in `ptr::copy_nonoverlapping`, `data` is referenced to get the write location. However since `data` is now a single byte on the stack and is not nearly large enough to hold the copied value, `copy_nonoverlapping` overwrites a ton of stuff on the stack leading to a segfault.

The solution is just cast `tvb.data` to a mutable pointer before passing it to `copy_nonoverlapping`. Raw pointers can break the mutability rules a bit since they are unsafe to read either way.

```rust
let mut tvb = bgfx::TransientVertexBuffer::new();
if bgfx::get_avail_transient_vertex_buffer(4, &builder) == 4 {
    bgfx::alloc_transient_vertex_buffer(&mut tvb, 4, &builder);
    unsafe {
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
            &vertices as *const u8,
            tvb.data as *mut u8,
            std::mem::size_of::<[f32; 16]>(),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it makes a lot of sense! I tried the same, but unfortunately still the same SIGSEGV did occurred (updated my question with the details)

Comment: Actually you were correct! There was a different issue in unrelated code as well causing an second SIGSEGV even after this change. Rectifying this did solve the problem - thank you very much!